# XCode 4.3.1 Installation

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xcode

I've recently installed XCode 4.3.1 which I downloaded from developer.apple.com site. Previously, I uninstalled an older version (XCode 4.1) by command line from /Developer/Applications... directory.

Now, I can't find any XCode directory at this point, neither I can't found XCode.app in /Applications folder.

Somebody knows where I can find XCode launcher, uninstaller or directory where I can run the app?

My OS: Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion)

Any help will be appreciated!

Regards.

Comment: I've found Xcode.app under /Developer/Applications directory, but I'm still searching for a launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Launcher and under Utilities you should find XCode.app icon. I found it there.

Comment: Thx denoth but I did't found it there. By now I've followed the next steps and it seems to be working:

1. Downloaded the image from developer.apple.com (I can't download it from appstore because I need an specific version, not the latest)

2. Ran downloaded image, and XCode launcher appears in finder. I copied it into Applications folder. So I can access it locally.

3. I clicked on Applications/XCode and then installed iOS Simulator and other components (Preferences menu).

I'll keep you posted for any update!

Comment: Hmm strange thing is that you don't have icon in the same place as I do. Anyway I got Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 Xcode 4.2. Let us know what you find. And if you need help